# array com problema json multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get a data that is in an array inside another array, I did a search by the forum and google and I made several attempts without success.
It seems like an easy catch but I'm breaking my head all day and I can not.

I'm leaving below my JSON code and my last attempt to pass to PHP. 
Thankful.

CODE JSON:

```
{
    "ordens_de_servico": [
        {
            "oser_numero_os": 23932944,
            "oser_nome_solicitante": "ED PI - CAMPO MAIOR",
            "oser_dt_abertura": "27/03/2018",
            "oser_pontos_refer_endereco": null,
            "oser_observ_reclamacao": null,
            "oser_prioridade": null,
            "servico": {
                "serv_cod_servico": 60,
                "serv_descr_servico": "CORTE POR DEBITO"
            },
            "cliente": {
                "nome": "ANTONIO WELTON DA SILVA OLIVEIRA",
                "telefone": " "
            },
            "unidade_consumidora": {
                "unid_ident_uc": 10945024,
                "logr_nome_logr_expandido": null,
                "medidor": "A2006171",
                "latitude": " -4.711808",
                "longitude": "-41.793455"
            },
            "faturas": [
                {
                    "total_fatura": "23.01"
                },
                {
                    "total_fatura": "17.88"
                },
                {
                    "total_fatura": "23.01"
                },
                {
                    "total_fatura": "21.9"
                },
                {
                    "total_fatura": "22.92"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**CODE PHP**

```
<?php

// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('oss.json');

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

//Print data
print_r($json_data);


$os = $json_data['ordens_de_servico'][0]['oser_numero_os']. PHP_EOL;
$data = $json_data['ordens_de_servico'][0]['oser_dt_abertura']. PHP_EOL;
$cod_serv = $json_data['ordens_de_servico']['servico'][0]['serv_cod_servico']. PHP_EOL;
$total_fatura = $json_data['ordens_de_servico']['faturas'][0]['total_fatura']. PHP_EOL;

echo $os."<p>";
echo $data."<p>";
echo $cod_serv."<p>";
echo $total_fatura."<p>";
?>
```

**I tried looping unsuccessfully on the fatura**

```
$json_data = json_decode($json,false);

foreach ( $json_data->ordens_de_servico as $valor){
        echo 'FATURA:'.$valor->faturas->total_fatura."<p>".PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: What is currently not working with your code?

Comment: this `$json_data['ordens_de_servico']['servico']` - `servico` just doesn't exist _there_: the `[0]` needs to be before the `['servico']`: `$json_data['ordens_de_servico'][0]['servico']['serv_cod_servico']`

Comment: @LioraHaydont $cod_serv = $json_data['ordens_de_servico']['servico'][0]['serv_cod_servico']. PHP_EOL;
$total_fatura = $json_data['ordens_de_servico']['faturas'][0]['total_fatura']. PHP_EOL;

Comment: Move some `[0]` and it will work.

Comment: @IsrayaneNayara What are you expecting these lines to do and what are they doing? is then an error code?

Comment: Please translate your title into English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, you are missing the [0] on these two lines:

```
$cod_serv = $json_data['ordens_de_servico']['servico'][0]['serv_cod_servico']. PHP_EOL;
$total_fatura = $json_data['ordens_de_servico']['faturas'][0]['total_fatura']. PHP_EOL;
```

They need to be:

```
$cod_serv = $json_data['ordens_de_servico'][0]['servico']['serv_cod_servico']. PHP_EOL;
$total_fatura = $json_data['ordens_de_servico'][0]['faturas'][0]['total_fatura']. PHP_EOL;
```

Example of looping through elements in arrays:

```
foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'] as $key => $value){
    echo $value["oser_numero_os"];
    foreach($json_data['ordens_de_servico'][$key]['faturas'] as $index => $row){

    }
}
```

Comment: @Syscall My bad, missed removing that initially. Edited the answer.

Comment: @Syscall Gave an error in: $cod_serv = $json_data['ordens_de_servico'][0]['servico'][0]['serv_cod_servico']. PHP_EOL;

Comment: @IsrayaneNayara Yes, I meant to remove the second [0] on that line as 'servico' is not an array. My answer has been updated.

Comment: Another question is how do I display multiple lines, since my json file has several array. Like a loop? I tried foreach without success.

Comment: @IsrayaneNayara Yes you'd use a foreach, just make sure to use it on only what is an array. I updated my answer with an example.